# Is the boundary of a polygon comprised in its interior?

Tags: topology, de-9im, ogc-sfa, sql-mm, ogc-sfs

I'm wondering, regarding the [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) and the OGC spatial predicates for expressing relationships between two geometries; is the boundary of a polygon *comprised* in its interior or not? If not, does it mean it's *comprised* in its exterior then?

I'm asking that because I cannot understand why the DE-9IM matrix of `POLYGON((0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 0))` and `LINESTRING(2 1, 5 5)` is `FF2F01102`, especially the two zeroes in there, in the sense that, if we can say that the intersection of the boundary of the polygon and the boundary of the line is a point (i.e. first of the two zeroes), then why the intersection of the exterior of the polygon and the line is *also* a point (second of the two zeroes) but not the intersection between the interior of the polygon and the line (which is Ø)?

```sql
SELECT ST_Relate(
    'POLYGON((0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 0))',
    'LINESTRING(2 1, 5 5)'
) AS rel;
    rel    
-----------
 FF2F01102
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by comprised?

Comment: If it's "part of", or "included" (if this actually does make sense, I'm not quite sure for the moment).

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no.

Details:
When using [JTS TestBuilder 1.19.0](https://github.com/locationtech/jts), I can say no, the boundary is not part of the interior of a polygon:

[image]

Also, [Clementini et al. (1993)](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-56869-7_16) said (p.5) that:

> The interior of a feature F, denoted by I, is defined as I = F - B, where B is the feature boundary.

The [OGC Simple Feature Access](https://www.ogc.org/standards/sfa) is based on that same hypothesis.

See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/446669/65370) for a more detailed explanation.

Source:

- "Clementini, E., Di Felice, P., van Oosterom, P. (1993). *A small set of formal topological relationships suitable for end-user interaction*. In: Abel, D., Chin Ooi, B. (eds) Advances in Spatial Databases. SSD 1993. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 692. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. [https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-56869-7_16"](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-56869-7_16%22)