# What exactly are the definitions of the boundary and interior of a line or a point?

Tags: topology, de-9im, ogc-sfa, ogc-sfs, sql-mm

Regarding the [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) and the OGC spatial predicates for expressing relationships between two geometries; I'm wondering what exactly are the *boundary* and *interior* of respectively a line and a point? Is it possible that those concept are just equal to Ø?

For example, [`ST_Touches`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html) between the two same points returns `False` which is a little awkward and counter-intuitive but I guess it *must* make sense, mathematically:

E.g. how to explain these results:

```sql
SELECT ST_Touches('POINT (1 1)','POINT (1 1)');
 st_touches 
------------
 f


SELECT ST_Relate('POINT (1 1)','POINT (1 1)');
 st_relate 
-----------
 0FFFFFFF2
```

But if the point is part of a line, then the first cell switches from `0` to `F` and the rest of the matrix changes quite a lot:

```sql
SELECT ST_Relate('POINT (1 1)','LINESTRING (1 1, 0 0)');
 st_relate 
-----------
 F0FFFF102
```

Comment: From my first observations, a point seems to only have some interior (no boundary).

Comment: I just looked it up in *Clementini, et. al.* (_A Small Set of Formal Topologoical Relationships Suitable for End-User Interaction_) -- in the latter half of section 2, it states "we consider the boundary of a point feature to be always empty. ... the boundary of a line is an empty set in the case of a circular line while otherwise is the set of the separate end-points." So both of my assertions were flawed (and now deleted).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, boundaries are always of dimension n-1 with respect to their parent element. Thus, the boundary of a polygon is of dimension 1 (linestring), the boundary of a linestring is of dimension 0 (point) and the boundary of a point does not exist (Ø).

As a complement, the interior of a polygon is the polygon itself minus its boundary, whereas the interior of a line is the line itself minus its boundary, and the interior of a point is the point itself minus its boundary -- which is an empty set Ø -- hence it's equal to the point itself.

This is corroborated by some tests I have done:

#### [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```py
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Point
print(shapely.__version__) # 1.8.5.post1

Point((1, 1)).boundary.geoms
>: []
```

#### [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/)

```sql
SELECT postgis_full_version();
------------------------------------------------
 POSTGIS="3.2.0 c3e3cc0" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="140"
    GEOS="3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0"
    PROJ="8.2.1"
    LIBXML="2.9.12"
    LIBJSON="0.15"
    LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
    WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Boundary(
        'POINT(2 1)'
)) AS boundary;

  boundary   
-------------
 POINT EMPTY
```

#### [JTS TestBuilder](https://github.com/locationtech/jts):

```
Point (3 2)

-> log:
Boundary.boundary( Point[1] ) : 61 ms
 ==> GeometryCollection[0]
```

I also found some articles on that topic:

[image]

[Source, p.6](http://www.geoinformations.developpement-durable.gouv.fr/fichier/pdf/Predicats_OGC_V3_cle119417.pdf?arg=177828548&cle=baf65cf1b040772ae1d97f164cf9ca67f6dbb698&file=pdf%2FPredicats_OGC_V3_cle119417.pdf) "Proteau, J.-C. Matrices de Clementini et Prédicats spatiaux de l'OGC, MEDDTL/SG/SPSSI/PSI1, september 2011"

[image]

[Source, p.517](https://www.mdpi.com/2220-9964/8/4/182/htm) "*Zhou, M.; Guan, Q. A 25-Intersection Model for Representing Topological Relations between Simple Spatial Objects in 3-D Space. ISPRS Int. J. Geo-Inf. 2019, 8, 182. [https://doi.org/10.3390/ijgi8040182*"](https://doi.org/10.3390/ijgi8040182*%22)

[image]

[Source pp 4-5](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-56869-7_16) "Clementini, E., Di Felice, P., van Oosterom, P. (1993). A small set of formal topological relationships suitable for end-user interaction. In: Abel, D., Chin Ooi, B. (eds) Advances in Spatial Databases. SSD 1993. Lecture Notes in Computer Science, vol 692. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. [https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-56869-7_16"](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-56869-7_16%22)

##### OGC SFA

https://www.ogc.org/standards/sfa

> ### 4.1
>
> #### boundary
>
> set that represents the limit of an entity
> NOTE Boundary is most commonly used in the context of geometry, where the set is a collection of points or a collection of objects that represent those points. In other arenas, the term is used metaphorically to describe the transition between an entity and the rest of its domain of discourse.

> #### 4.16
>
> ##### interior
>
> set of all direct positions (4.7) that are on a geometric object (4.14) but which are not on its boundary (4.1)
> The concepts of interior, boundary and exterior are well defined as sets of
> point geometry, and abstracted in general topology; see Reference (5).

> #### 6.1.15 Relational operators
>
> ##### 6.1.15.1 Background
>
> The boundary of a geometric object is a set of geometric objects of the next lower dimension. The boundary of a Point or a MultiPoint is the empty set. The boundary of a non-closed Curve consists of its two end Points; the boundary of a closed Curve is empty. The boundary of a MultiCurve consists of those Points that are in the boundaries of an odd number of its element Curves. The boundary of a Polygon consists of its set of Rings. The boundary of a MultiPolygon consists of the set of Rings of its Polygons. The boundary of an arbitrary collection of geometric objects whose interiors are disjoint consists of geometric objects drawn from the boundaries of the element geometric objects by application of the “mod 2” union rule (Bibliographic Reference (2), section 3.12.3.2).

[Source, p.8,10,32-33](https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=25355) "OpenGIS Implementation Specification for Geographic information - Simple feature access - Part 1: Common architecture"
Based on: ISO 19107:2019 https://www.iso.org/standard/66175.html